# Is There An Ansible Task To Create Services

Tags: linux, ansible

Ansible has a task to ensure services (systemd in this case)  are started or stopped etc.

However, is there a task to create the service?

Right now I am copying a template to the correct directory to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that creation of unit files with template module is the right way.